# How to display metadata on a site page

Tags: metadata

Using Sharepoint Online, modern pages.
I'd like to show metadata of a page, on the page itself. Some of this is default metadata, some of it is custom metadata.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: metadata means you want to show the page information like created on, author, page title etc?

Comment: Yes. Vipul below had the answer I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your modern page and open the menu to add a webpart. There is a "Page Properties" webpart where you can configure the properties which you want to display on the page. However, at the moment I can only see the custom metadata and the title field showing up and not the CreatedBy or ModifiedBy properties

More information : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-page-properties-web-part-1a99cb9c-a5f1-441b-8e5d-643b0f0ff736

I believe for default metadata such as Author, Created, Modified you may have to build a custom SPFx webpart that fetches this information for the current page and displays it. If you want to have this on all the site pages, you'll need a provisioning process to place the webpart automatically when a page is created or place it manually when you create a page.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's the one. This wasn't available to me as I was in the standard release program. I had to move to the targeted release to get it. I have the same problem with what metadata is available, seems to be limited at the moment.