# How to display metadata on a site page - SharePoint 2016?

Tags: metadata, properties

Similar to ([How to display metadata on a site page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/245770/how-to-display-metadata-on-a-site-page)), I'm trying to figure out how to display page metadata on the page itself (like ModifiedBy and Modified date, as well as some custom metadata columns).  Is there a way to do this in SP2016, without changing the master file?